# Sequence generation problem - Fibonacci

Tags: python, python-3.x, fibonacci-sequence

Below is the representation and user interface `fib_sequence` for generating a Fibonacci sequence:

```
empty_rlist = None
#Representation - start
#Constructor
def rlist(first, rest):
    return (first, rest)

#Selector
def first(s):
    return s[0]

def rest(s):
    return s[1]

#Representation - end

def fib_sequence(k):
    prev, curr = 1, 0
    def generate_sequence(prev, curr, k):
        if k == 0:
           return empty_rlist
        elif k == 1:
           return (curr, empty_rlist)
        else:
           return rlist(curr, generate_sequence(curr, prev+curr, k - 1))
    return generate_sequence(prev, curr, k)
```

Program output:

> ```
> >python -i fibonacci_sequence.py
> >>> fib_sequence(0)
> >>> fib_sequence(1)
> (0, None)
> >>> fib_sequence(2)
> (0, (1, None))
> >>> fib_sequence(3)
> (0, (1, (1, None)))
> >>> fib_sequence(4)
> (0, (1, (1, (2, None))))
> >>> fib_sequence(5)
> (0, (1, (1, (2, (3, None)))))
> ```

The above program provides representation as `(element, restOfTheList)`.

We have this sequence containers in Python:

```
>>> tuple =  (1, 2, 3, 4)
>>> r = range(1,5)
>>> str = '1234'
```

Is the representation of the aforementioned Python sequence containers same as the above representation of the Fibonacci sequence abstraction?

If no, can we make the representation of the Fibonacci sequence abstraction better, basically to forward this sequence for further processing by sequence processing functions like `map()` `filter()` `sum()` etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call `rlist()` consistently, and write

```
elif k == 1:
    return rlist(curr, empty_rlist)
```

… for reasons that will become apparent.  Also be sure to use four spaces per level of indentation, [as prescribed by PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation).

Are your tuple, range, and string the same as each other?  No, comparing them using `==` will obviously return `False`.  What they all have in common, though, is that they are all [iterables](//stackoverflow.com/a/9884259/1157100).  Being iterable means that you can use them in `for e in iterable` expressions — either in a loop or a generator.

That means that if you want to be able to write things like `print([e for e in fib_sequence(5)])`, you'll need to make your `rlist` type iterable.  Here's one way you could accomplish that.

```
class rlist(tuple):
    def __new__(cls, first, rest):
        return super(rlist, cls).__new__(cls, (first, rest))

    def __iter__(self):
        seq = self
        while seq is not None:
            yield first(seq)
            seq = rest(seq)
```

This works as long as you have applied the `rlist()` fix to `fib_sequence()` as mentioned above.

Comment: Note: `iter(fib_sequence(0))` fails with `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable`. Suggestions for fixing that would be welcome.

Comment: For your point: "comparing them using == will obviously return False",  Who(object) owns this == functionality? How does that owner know about the representation aspect of these 3 abstractions to compare 3 sequence types? Because representation aspect of `string`/`tuple`/`range` abstraction would be different.

Comment: Read about [`object.__eq__()`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__eq__)

Comment: Are `map` / `filter` / `sum` are also relying on this iterable concept to work seem less on `string`/`tuple`/`range` sequence type?

Comment: The documentation says that [`map()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map), [`filter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter), and [`sum()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) all accept iterables.

Comment: When I say, `>>> s = 'cat'  >>> t = iter(s)  >>> char1 = next(t) >>> char1
'c'`, Being a dynamic type language, `char1` stores any type data. In contrast, If I use a static type language like Java in such situation, what would be the type of `char1`, How do I decide that?

Comment: Unfortunately the Java analogue doesn't work — you [can't write `for (c : "hello")`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13470902/1157100) because strings do not implement [`Iterable<Character>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/foreach.html).

Comment: is iterator concept relevent to sequential type only not for tree graph etc

Comment: Why shouldn't you be able to iterate over a tree?

Answer (score -3):

I'm no ninja coder, still though I know to handle myself. Your function does not need to take three arguments, you just need two. Avoid adding many conditions when iterating, it makes it slower.
The most optimized solution I could find was this, is 10 times faster

```
def Fibonacci(n):
    a,b=0,1
    for i in range(n):
        a, b = b, a+b
    return a
```

Comment: Sorry, what is ninja?

Comment: The correct term is "killer coding ninja monkey guru handsome hero sexmachine."

Comment: The original code returns the entire sequence up to that point; your solution returns just the last number.